# Can a Google Document get programmatically created from HTML form data?

Tags: php, google-docs

I've written a simple web app that creates a MS Word document from an HTML form (using JavaScript and PHP also) but I've since converted to Google Docs.

After spending most of the day trying to see if switching from .docx's to .gdoc's was doable (perhaps with a different PHP plugin), I can't seem to find a way to programmatically create a Google Doc without using Google Scripts or a server running Google App Engine.

My question:  Can a Google Document get programmatically created using PHP and an HTML form?

Comment: Doesn't google docs support the docx format?

Comment: Yes, which is how I converted all my docx's to gdoc's but instead of having my App create a docx that then needs to be converted, I was wondering if I could directly create a gdoc. I can't seem to find any guidance on how to do so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check the Google Drive SDK documentation for everything related to Google Docs: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk

An easy way to push files in would be to upload them: https://developers.google.com/drive/web/manage-uploads#simple

Comment: I spent a long time searching for documentation.  This was not easy to get to!  Thanks for your help.